# Identifying missing data in a range

Tags: vba, excel

I'm looking to set up a VBA macro which automatically runs through a list of data in a column and picks out the missing values. The code I've got at the moment (see below) works, but I believe it starts looking in cell A2. I'd like it to start in B1.

How could I make this change?

Apologies, I'm a beginner to VBA!

```
Sub Check_Sequential()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
ALR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
x = 2
Cells(1, 3) = "Missing Numbers"
For i = 2 To LR
0
    If Cells(i, 1) <> x Then
        Cells(ALR, 3) = x
        ALR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        x = x + 1
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If

    If Cells(i, 1) > x Then GoTo 0

    If Cells(i, 1) = x Then
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: use Cells(i, 2) but did you still want to use column A to determine last row?

Comment: change the for statement to i=1 instead of i=2 and change the first if statement into cells(i,2) instead of cells(i,1)

Comment: Aren't you incrementing x twice if Cells(i,1)=x?

Comment: That `0` line number is ambiguous - use line labels instead, e.g. `BeginningOfLoop:` - that way `On Error GoTo 0` won't get your code into some weird funky state, or worse, into an unfortunate infinite loop. Line number 0 should be illegal to use... please loose that habit! Read up on `On Error Resume Next` and `On Error GoTo 0` if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to move from cell A2 to B1 for the search start range you would need the following changes to your code. This just addresses the area you defined your initial search:

```
Sub Check_Sequential()

Dim LR As Long, i As Long

LR = ActiveSheet.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row '// Changed from "A" to "B"
ALR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
x = 2
Cells(1, 3) = "Missing Numbers"
For i = 1 To LR '// Chaged i to one to start at row 1 instead of 2
0
    If Cells(i, 2) <> x Then '// Changed from i,1 to i,2
        Cells(ALR, 3) = x
        ALR = ActiveSheet.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        x = x + 1
    Else
        x = x + 1
    End If

    If Cells(i, 2) > x Then GoTo 0 '// Changed from i,1 to i,2

    If Cells(i, 2) = x Then '// Changed from i,1 to i,2
        x = x + 1
    End If
Next i
MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

This should allow your code to work, although as a few others pointed out there are a few things you could look into to further develop your VBA skills:

- Declare all variables with a type this will make your code more readable and stop them defaulting to variant (Eg `ALR`)
- Avoid using 0 as a line name as "`On Error GoTo 0`" is how you restore to default error handling and this could be misleading
- It is clearer to edit the cells value by using the "`.value`" property and it would work exactly the same in this case
- It might be worth clearing your output column before writing as this code will stack the output on top of the older ones, not sure if this is intend though.

Although it was not a bad piece of code especially consider you classify yourself as a beginner.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. This code works great, but one problem I have noticed is if my column begins with anything bigger than 1, the code will list all numbers from 1 up to my first actual value. The data columns I'm working with are completely variable, so sometimes B1 could be 1679, sometimes 256, sometimes 83757. Any thoughts? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @L.TK - I would suggest looking at where you set `X=2` on line 7 and instead set it to the minimum value of the range. Also if your question has been answered please tick an answer as correct so it flags correctly to other users, you will still be able to comment.

Comment: That seems to have done it! I've tried a basic workaround, by using VBA to run a MIN function in a certain cell, then setting X to be the value in that cell. Seems to have done the trick.

Comment: @L.TK Glad to hear you got it to work in the end. Although a tip for the future would be to use `Application.WorksheetFunction.Min(RANGE)` as this will let you evaluate the function without writing it into a cell. In fact you can call any excel function in this way just replace `min` with whatever function you wan to evaluate.

Answer (score 0):

My dear friend Steven Roman tells us that Cells is not an "official" collection or object... but it is really useful.  Cells is equivalent to Application.Cells and Activesheet.Cells.

Cells(1,2) is equivalent to Range("B1").  I like Cells() better than Range() because it can take integer variables for row and column like your i and x, while Range doesn't like that.

Comment: `Cells` is a `Property Get` accessor on the hidden `_Global` module, and returns a `Range`. As such, using it unqualified means identical code will behave differently depending on whether the code is written in a worksheet's code-behind, or in a standard or class module. Whether you prefer to use `Cells` or `Range`, you should always qualify them with the worksheet you mean to work against - and if that's the `ActiveSheet`, then qualify with `ActiveSheet` explicitly. That way you're writing code that says what it does, and does what it says.